# Xcode 9 Swift 4 UITableView unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I just moved from obj-c to swift and i am having problem with the UITableView inside a UIViewController

I have set the delegate and data source from the Interface Builder from the TableView to the View Controller, but it doesn't work fine

here is the screenshot

[image]

and here is my view controller

```
class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
var cellRow = ["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"]

 // MARK: - TableView Delegates
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellRow.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let object = cellRow[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.description
    return cell
}
```

Here is the error

```
reason: '-[MyApp.SideMenuViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

However, if i set the delegate and data source manually by using code inside the view controller, it will work. Is it a bug??

Thanks

Comment: I guess you forgot to add `UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource` after `UIViewController`.

Comment: When using obj-c i dont have to add those manually inside my view controller, just from Interface Builder and it is set

Comment: @Alvin, right. But this is Swift so that’s not really relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must add `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`. Delegate class have to tell compiler that we are adopting the protocol and then implement the delegate method(s).

```
class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // ...    
}
```

Another good looking way is to implement protocols and delegates is by using extension.

```
class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController {
    // ..        
}

extension SideMenuViewController : UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let object = cellRow[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = object.description
        return cell
    }
}

extension SideMenuViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellRow.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, looks like it is a must to include those 2 inside the view controllers. Because in obj-c we can just set it from IB and not necessary to add those 2 inside the view controller. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, You are right it works in obj-c but in swift you have mention it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Alvin There is another swifty way is by using extensions. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 4

You can just add delegate like this

**Step 1 :** `class ViewController: VVBaseViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

**Step 2** Implement Delegate And DataSource Method

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 20 // Here is 20 section in tableview and 1 row each section.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1 // Only 1 row in each section
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Normal Cell (UITableViewCell)
    //        let cell:UITableViewCell = (tblProperty!.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell?)!
    
    // Custom Cell
    let cell:CellSubService = tblSubServices.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! CellSubService
    
    cell.lblServiceName.text = "Test Service"
    cell.lblRate.text = "$5 / Sq.Ft"
    
    return cell
}
```